# conversion of multiple line into list comphrension python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I have python code similar to the following

```
for a in range(0,x):
 print("test")
 print("test2")
 if a%2==0:
  l1.append(a)
```

could it be converted into list comprehensions or is there other way to reduce it.

Comment: The loop has two responsibilities. I'd split it into two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generation of the list can be converted into a list comprehension, but the print statements cannot be done in one line:

```
x = 10
l1 = [a for a in range(0, x) if a % 2 == 0]
```

Will give you the list, if you want also the `print` statements, more work is needed, e.g. define a function that is called while the list is built:

```
def foo(a):
    print('Test1')
    print('Test2')
    return a

l2 = [a for a in range(0, x) if foo(a) % 2 == 0]
```

This latter option is however "a code smell", generating a list while relying for output on the side-effect of a function is not a good practice (very error prone in an even moderately large program). I would not recommend the latter.

Comment: defined like that, you can use `foo` in condition instead so the print is executed all the time instead of half of the time

Answer (score 1):

*"could it be converted into list comprehensions"*?

It certainly could:

```
x = 10
l1 = [a for a in range(x) if a % 2 == 0]
```

Comment: There is no output

Comment: @PeterWood No, the `print` statements aren't there. It would be easy to include them but I chose not to since it's best practice to keep list comprehensions self-contained and free of side effects . Besides, I didn't think they mattered much to the OP anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Not recommended but you can actually output the text and store the elements because print is a function in python3:

```
l = [print("test\ntest2") or a for a in range(5) if not a % 2]
```

In python2 you would need to `from __future__ import print_function`